# How do max and union commute in Hausdorff measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, fractals

Recall that $d_H(A,B) = \max\{\max_{a \in A} \min_{b \in B} d(a,b),\max_{b \in B} \min_{a \in A} d(a,b)\}$

> **Theorem:** Let $A,B,C \in H(X)$ (where $H(X)$ is the set of non-empty compact subsets of $X$).  Then $d_H(A \cup B,C) = \max \{d_H(A,C),d_H(B,C)\}$

This claim appears in the book on fractals and splines by Peter Massopust. However, I'm not able to connect the hint below with the statement of the theorem:

> *Proof:* Note that
>   \begin{align}
> d(A\cup B, C) &= \max_{\alpha\in A\cup B} d(\alpha, C) = \max\left\{ \max_{\alpha\in A} d(\alpha,C), \max_{\alpha\in B} d(\alpha,C)\right\} \\
> &= \max\{ d(A,C), d(B,C)\}
> \end{align}
>   which implies that claim.  (The reader is encouraged to verify this).

It seems that the definition of $d$ is (see the book Fractals everywhere) taken to be $d(A,B) = max\{d(a,B):a \in A\}$. So the above hint makes sense.

So how can I use this hint to prove my theorem?

**My try:**

$d_H(A \cup B,C) = \max \{d(A \cup B,C) , d(C, A \cup B) \}$

by definition. Then, by the hint:

$d_H(A \cup B,C) = \max \{\max\{d(A \cup B,C), d(C,A \cup B)\} , d(C, A \cup B) \}$

then, I take the other member:

$\max\{d_H(A,C),d_H(B,C)\} = \max \{\max\{d(A,C), d(C,A)\} , \{\max\{d(B,C), d(C,B)\} \}$

again by definition. Two terms are in the two sides, but I would need an equality of the sort $d(C,A \cup B) = \max \{d(C,A),d(C,B)\}$. This reduces to show:

$\max_{c \in C}\{\min_{a \in A \cup B} d(c,a)\} = \max\{\max_{c \in C}\{min_{a \in A} d(c,a),\max_{c \in C}\{min_{a \in B} d(c,a)\}\}$

Comment: Where, specifically, are you stuck?  There are three equalities in the quoted text, as well as, perhaps, some ambiguity in the last sentence.  What, specifically, are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keypoint is the following inequality:

$d(C, A \cup B) = \max\limits_{c \in C} \min\limits_{x \in A \cup B} d(c,x) = \max\limits_{c \in C} \min \{ \min\limits_{a \in A} d(c,a), \min\limits_{b \in B} d(c,b)\} \le \min\{ \max\limits_{c \in C} \min\limits_{a \in A} d(c,a), \max\limits_{c \in C} \min\limits_{b \in B} d(c,b) \} = \min \{ d(C,A),d(C,B) \}$

This inequality gives us that:

$d(C,A \cup B) \le d(C,A),d(C,B) \implies d(C,A \cup B) \le \max\{d(C,A),d(C,B)\}$.

On the other hand, we also know that:

$d(B \cup C, A) = \max\limits_{b \in B \cup C} \min\limits_{a \in A} d(b,a) = \max\{\max\limits_{b \in B} \min\limits_{a \in A} d(b,a),\max\limits_{b \in C} \min\limits_{a \in A} d(b,a)\} = \max\{d(B,A),d(C,A)\}$.

Finally,

$d_H(A \cup B,C) = \max \{d(C,A \cup B),d(A \cup B,C) \} \le \max \{ d(C,A),d(A,C),d(C,B),d(B,C)\} = \max\{d_H(A,C),d_H(B,C)\}$

The other inequality is immediate, since:

$d_H(A,C),d_H(B,C) \le d_H(A \cup B,C)$

so that $\max\{d_H(A,C),d_H(B,C)\} \le d_H(A \cup B,C)$.

**References**: Barnsley's "Superfractals", 2006.

Comment: In your penultimate line you claim that "$d_H(A,C),d_H(B,C) \le d_H(A \cup B,C)$"; is this obvious?